Questions about installing an electric shower
I will plug my shower into a common socket plug. I can't tell if my house's network has a grounding. I saw a product called ''Electronic Grounding'' that aims to replace grounding. I would like to know if I use this device, will it reduce the risk of me getting an electric shock in my shower? Another thing is, can I use an iClamper on this ''electronic grounding'' so that it is safer against electric shocks?

Your general location is needed.  Most sockets with three holes should be grounded, but testing is good.   ''electronic grounding''  sounds like our GFCI sockets/receptacles.

Electric shower?

@gnicko,  In some countries, there is no central hot water heater. Water is heated at the needed appliance. Often showers have piping that flows into a "heating box" and then out to the shower head.  This is often a unit that plugs into a socket , sometimes near the top of the shower.  Nothing like we have in the US.

Here in Brazil the shower is electric. Inside the shower there is a resistance

Here is an "electric shower"  https://www.amazon.com/FOSET-49491-Electric-Shower/dp/B00V8IT7KC/ref=pd_lpo_sccl_1/131-0374393-9055403?pd_rd_w=kMhqd&content-id=amzn1.sym.1ad2066f-97d2-4731-9356-36b3edf1ae04&pf_rd_p=1ad2066f-97d2-4731-9356-36b3edf1ae04&pf_rd_r=CGRPQXETM1CT970S7NYZ&pd_rd_wg=lwWey&pd_rd_r=56e65235-61ed-4c55-a3ed-9c1fd236170e&pd_rd_i=B00V8IT7KC&psc=1

Looks kind of cool. I'd feel really vulnerable without a physical ground on the circuit. Not sure I'd trust "electronic grounding" or any product with "i" in front of the name... That's just "me" tho.

iCLAMPER is a surge protector, it will not protect you against electrical faults in your appliance.  https://www.lojaclamper.com.br/dps-iclamper-pocket-3-pinos-10a/p

@Jasen, make that an answer. + 1 upvote.

I don't what the other device "electronic grounding" is.

At a wild guess. "electronic grounding" may be a horrible description of GFCI, which can provide safety protection similar to grounding. However, if a hardwired product calls for grounding it should be grounded, with GFCI as an additional layer of protection. And, yeah, electric showers terrify this American on principle; at least put the heater outside the splash zone!

Find the ground
Open the circuit breaker box, there should be the ground.
Use a multimeter and measure between the 3 pins on the plug.
You should see the voltage twice (from hot to the ground, from hot to neutral.
The manufacturer requires ground to be connected.

